# Yii2 data provider default sorting

Tags: php, yii, yii2, gridview-sorting

In Yii 1.1 this code works for default sorting:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('article',array(
    'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>'id DESC',
    ),
));
```

How default sorting can be set in Yii2?

Tried below code, but no result:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort' => ['defaultOrder'=>'topic_order asc']
]);
```

Answer (score 200, accepted):

I think there's proper solution. Configure the [`yii\data\Sort`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-sort) object:

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query' => $query,
     'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['topic_order' => SORT_ASC]],
 ]);
```

[Official doc link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/output-data-providers.md)

Comment: This solution works but the search in index doesn't work now.

Answer (score 42):

Or

```
       $dataProvider->setSort([
        'defaultOrder' => ['topic_order'=>SORT_DESC],
        'attributes' => [...
```

Comment: It's more compatible with default GII output

Answer (score 18):

**defaultOrder** contain a array where key is a column name and value is a  `SORT_DESC` or  `SORT_ASC` that's why below code not working.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder'=>'topic_order asc']
    ]);
```

**Correct Way**

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'topic_order' => SORT_ASC,
        ]
    ],
]);
```

Note: If a query already specifies the orderBy clause, the new ordering instructions given by end users (through the sort configuration) will be appended to the existing orderBy clause. Any existing limit and offset clauses will be overwritten by the pagination request from end users (through the pagination configuration).

You can detail learn from 
[Yii2 Guide of Data Provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html)

Sorting By passing Sort object in query

```
 $sort = new Sort([
        'attributes' => [
            'age',
            'name' => [
                'asc' => ['first_name' => SORT_ASC, 'last_name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['first_name' => SORT_DESC, 'last_name' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Name',
            ],
        ],
    ]);

    $models = Article::find()
        ->where(['status' => 1])
        ->orderBy($sort->orders)
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 13):

if you have CRUD (index) and you need set default sorting your controller for GridView, or ListView, or more...
Example

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new NewsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    // set default sorting
    $dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder = ['id' => SORT_DESC];

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

you need add

```
$dataProvider->sort->defaultOrder = ['id' => SORT_DESC];
```

Comment: if you want to do it in the controller without changing the SearchModel, this is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try to this one

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);

$sort = $dataProvider->getSort();

$sort->defaultOrder = ['id' => SORT_ASC];

$dataProvider->setSort($sort);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([ 
    'query' => $query, 
    'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['iUserId'=>SORT_ASC]] 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  sort properties like this

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
 'query' => $query,
 'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['topic_order' => SORT_ASC]],]);
```

if you want to sort by two feild for examle topic_order1 and topic_order2 you can do like this

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
 'query' => $query,
 'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['topic_order1' => SORT_ASC,
'topic_order2' =>SORT_DESC]]]);
```

Comment: Hi, your answer does not add anything new; please do not copy&paste other's work without  mentioning the sources . Read help: [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers), you must specify the sorting behaviors of a data provider by configuring its sort properties which correspond to the configurations for yii\data\Sort

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query' => $query,
         'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['topic_order' => SORT_ASC]],
     ]);
```

Comment: Duplicated answer. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22994046/1030070 which is from 2014 has already the same code and has been marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

you can modify search model like this

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => ['user_id ASC, document_id ASC']
        ]
    ]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    $modelProduct       =   new Product();
    $shop_id            =   (int)Yii::$app->user->identity->shop_id;

    $queryProduct       =   $modelProduct->find()
                            ->where(['product.shop_id'  => $shop_id]);


    $dataProviderProduct    =   new ActiveDataProvider([
                                    'query'         =>  $queryProduct,
                                     'pagination' => [ 'pageSize' => 10 ],
                                    'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id'=>SORT_DESC]]
                                ]);
```